# Which fontawesome file should I include and why others do not work

Tags: wordpress, icons, font-awesome-5

I am working on a WordPress theme and tried many times to add fontawesome icons. Finally, by adding different fontawesome CSS files I found few of them works well but not others.
Please tell me why others do not work and which one should I use.

all.min.css file shows this result.

[image: fontawesome icons]

I have used the different to see which one works. "fa/far/fad/fas"

```
<div class="fa-3x">
  <i class="fad fa-camera"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-fire-alt"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bus-alt"></i>
  <i class="far fa-fill-drip"></i>
</div>
```

And the functions.php file where I have added the CSS file to include in the header file.

```
...
//FontAwesome CSS file
    wp_enqueue_style( 'epostlite-fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fontawesome/css/all.min.css' );
...
```

I used version 5

- Why "fad" and "far" shows a rectangle instead of the icon?
- Why "fontawesome.min.css" and "brands.min.css do not work?

Comment: I just do not get how to use it. Where only a few icons are working fa-facebook or others are not showing up on pages.

Answer (score 2):

**Why "fad" and "far" shows a rectangle instead of the icon?**

Because fad & far are pro icons so both will not work in free version.

**Why "fontawesome.min.css" and "brands.min.css do not work?**

This both will work but you need to add one more css, which is

```
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome-solid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/font-awesome5/solid.min.css');
```

after adding `solid.min.css` you will get same result as `all.min.css`

But preferable is if you are using font awesome version 5 then just use `all.min.css`, no need to include all of them differently. you can check it from [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use).

Comment: When I need one `fas` icon, is the `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/solid.min.css` enough?

Answer (score 0):

Instead adding more & differrent kind of css you can fix the problem in less then 2 mins. Simple replacement of /font-awesome/5.13.0/css/fontawesome.min.css with /font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css and also font-awesome/5.13.0/js/fontawesome.min.js with /font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js can fix this issue. I prefer to use cdnjs

https://youtu.be/_GV_pEmLCLU